# Displaying a table from mssql server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have written a code to connect to my SQL server which is successful but it only displays the column name with no corresponding value from the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php    
$serverName = "VM4FE8D04";   
$databaseName = "NNPC-ChevronScholarship";   

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$databaseName);                               


/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM ExamSlip";    

/* Execute the query. */    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);    

if ( $stmt )    
{    
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";    
}     
else     
{    
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.*/    

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))    
{    
     echo "Name: ".$row[Names]."\n";    
     echo "Application No: ".$row[ApplicationNo]."\n";    
     echo "Serial No: ".$row[SerialNo]."<br>\n";    
     echo "-----------------<br>\n";    
}    

/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);    
?>
```

Comment: What does `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)
```

then the resulted array should be referenced as

```
$row[0], $row[1],....
```

I suggest you use

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
```

then you can use the names of the columns to reference the assoc array

```
$row['Names'], $row['ApplicationNo'], etc
```

but the column names must be wrapped in quotes as above.

Comment: How DO I tweak it to show only a user's image in the table

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQLSERV_FETCH_ASSOC` to get data in associative array

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSERV_FETCH_ASSOC))    
{    
     echo "Name: ".$row['Names']."\n";    
     echo "Application No: ".$row['ApplicationNo']."\n";    
     echo "Serial No: ".$row['SerialNo']."<br>\n";    
     echo "-----------------<br>\n";    
}
```

This will solved your problem.